# Make parent not working on bones

Tags: parent

When I want make parent on two bones its not working.

What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bones need to be in the same armature, it's probably not the case here, so switch to *Object* mode and join the 2 armatures with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.